# Brackets around tags disappear from search after captcha

Tags: bug, tags, search, captcha

I clicked a tag from a user profile on a site where I don't have an account. The address was:

> https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:2306+[transactions]

It then took me to the "nocaptcha" page which I passed (with flying colors) by clicking the magic checkbox. I was then redirected to the search, but with brackets that surrounded the tag removed:

> https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:2306+transactions&s=my_session_key

Clearly the brackets should be retained through this captcha detour.